# Ethernet interface not found - eth0

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I booted an OS from a live CD. The OS boots successfully but eth0 fails to start. I checked `lspci`, it outputs these Ethernet card details:

```
(Broadcom Netextreme II BCM5716 GBabyte ethernet)
```

`ifconfig -a` returns only the loopback interfaces `lo` and `sit0`. The output of `dmesg | grep -I 'eth'` is:

```
"Netfront : initializing network ethernet driver"
```

When I run `service network restart` I get:

```
"Obtaining IP for lo [FAILED]
WARNING: Deprecated config gile /etc/modprobe.conf , all config files belong into /etc/modprobe.d/
Device eth0 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization [FAILED]"
```

The output of `MII-tool -v` is:

```
No MII interface found.
```

I was also able to find the kernel module `bnx2.ko`. I did `insmod` and `lsmod` lists it. I am not sure what exactly is the issue or how to debug this problem. Any assistance or pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that device also requires a separate PHY driver to be compiled. Look in the PHY section of the kernel config and select all of them as modules, just to be sure.

Comment: Can you please provide some more information regarding the PHY driver or how to verify ? I am not very familiar with this.

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: I am not sure. It s gridentric. It uses redhat based one i guess !