# r8152 eth0: intr status -EOVERFLOW

Tags: linux, networking

I get this message non-stop when booting on linux:

```
r8152 1-2:1.0 eth0: intr status -EOVERFLOW
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Eth0 is referring to your ethernet connection. Not sure for the rest.

Comment: Yeah, I issue is what comes after that. r8152 is the model of the chipset of my card (Realtek 8152), I can't find any information about -EOVERFLOW

Comment: A NIC card I assume? Has it ever worked before?

Comment: Yes, it normally works. It just happens some time. I usually force shutdown and restart, and then it works, but not always.

Comment: I don't know really then but you could go through a few checks like reinstalling the driver, ensuring the driver is supported by your linux flavor, etc

Comment: See related as it may be relevant to you https://superuser.com/questions/312143/ethernet-interface-not-found-eth0?rq=1

Comment: I've tried recompiling the kernel with the latest driver, but the error still appears randomly.